# What are the grammatical rules for use of "these", "those", and "them"?

Tags: word-choice, pronouns, determiners

> I am unclear of the use of [these|those] objects. I am unsure when to use [these|those|them].

Please someone help me tell me which is correct in the previous sentences.

This is not a dupe of [What's the difference between "these" and "those"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19772/whats-the-difference-between-these-and-those)

Comment: _Them_ doesn't belong to the same paradigm as _these_ and _those_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*These, those and them* may all be used as objects of a sentence or a preposition.

Said when no books are present:

> I lost my books. Did you see them?

Said while pointing toward a flock of geese:

> I see some geese. Do you see those?

Said while holding a handful of diamonds.

> I found some diamonds. Did you see these?

You can also use two of the three as modifiers for nouns:

> Did you those geese?
>
> Did you see these diamonds?

**But it is ungrammatical to say**

> Did you see them books?

Comment: So, my sentences should read, "I am unclear of the use of those objects [I am point at the objects]. I am unsure when to use these."

Comment: @Carnotaurus: One thing to remember between these/those. Usually "these" will be used for things in the near field (e.g., between you and your interlocutor), and "those" for things that are at some distance from you both.

Comment: What about if object are intangible (like bank accounts) or spatial in some of other, such that distance is unknown, cannot be gauged, or does not apply?

Comment: Then you would be more likely to use *those*: "I have some shares in Google. Did you see how those have shot up recently?" But you could also use *these*: "Liver, kidney, organ meats of any kind — these are the foods I hate most." Sorry to say, but the subtleties of usage here must simply be learned from experience (i.e. reading).

Comment: Thanks, you have more than clarified the usage of these words and their senses.

Comment: _Them books_ is perfectly fine in some dialects like my own (SAE).  I would never recommend it in Standard English, but it is grammatical in some parts of the Anglosphere.

Answer (score -4):

I think your answers on how to use "these"  and "those" are incorrect.  I was taught to  use a noun after both these and those. EX: these apples....those apples.  these and those always need a noun after them, them and they do not. One needs to always answer
these_______?  Or, those **______**?
     what               what

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to tell.