# Is it possible to use an object pronoun (them) in the place of a subject pronoun (they)?

Tags: subjects

I have seen an episode of *Mindhunter* S1:E9, in on the scenes there is a sentence that has driven my attention:

A: "I'm not like them"

B: "No?"

A: "Them f*ckers are crazy."

Is it possible to use an object pronoun (them) in the place of a subject pronoun (they)?

Comment: Closely related: [Using “them” instead of “those”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/150674/using-them-instead-of-those) and [What are the grammatical rules for use of “these”, “those”, and “them”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21457/what-are-the-grammatical-rules-for-use-of-these-those-and-them)

Comment: It isn't used in place of a subject pronoun. We wouldn't say "They fuckers are crazy". It's used in place of a demonstrative determiner (like "those" or "these").

Comment: Also related: [Use of “them” as an article, not a pronoun](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30249/use-of-them-as-an-article-not-a-pronoun)