# highly recommended for those and highly recommended for these

Tags: meaning, grammar, phrases, differences

what is different between highly recommended for those and highly recommended for these?

and I am also wondering if I can use 'highly recommended for those' only as a sentence.
for example, if I wanna sell a product and wanna recommend this product to some specific group of people to buy it, like some people who are tired and who eat lots of fast foods. 
in that situation, can I use this phrase/sentence 'highly recommended for those' and explain what kind of people I recommend in the second sentence?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between "these" and "those"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19772/whats-the-difference-between-these-and-those)

Comment: As for the second part of your question, it wouldn't work as two completely separate sentences. It would need to be something like this: *It is highly recommended for [these / those] people: the tired and the fast-food consumers.* Generally speaking, *these* works better in that example sentence. *Those* could be used if you'd already mentioned some people earlier, and are perhaps now giving them a different description.